# Limit the max-height to fit the content size

Tags: css

I have a resizable container, I want it to be able to be resized to fit the content inside, but not too large to waste space.

I got the code like

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: max-content;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, molestiae? Officiis consequatur quod minima cum at ratione, sint ipsum architecto! Sit accusantium tenetur ducimus aut atque, eligendi in ullam sunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Maxime explicabo dolor sequi veritatis aut. Recusandae quibusdam maiores doloremque natus, aspernatur minus dignissimos, id soluta amet, blanditiis illum odio ab alias.
  </div>
</div>
```

I try different value of max-height, only fixed value such as 300px works, but it is not what I want. The requirement is that the red space can not be there, like the attachment. Any idea? [image]

Answer (score 4):

Try `height: fit-content;`

---

**UPDATE**

At first I didn't understand what you were trying to achieve, but now I'm pretty sure what you need here.

Unfortunately, I think that this is impossible without javascript (I may be wrong).

So here is simple example with [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) that looks for `container` and if this element height exceeds `content` height it will be shrinked back to max height of `content`.

disconnecting observer before change of height and reconnecting back after this change is mandatory because change of height will trigger `ResizeObserver` and we will got and infinite loop.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/WICG/resize-observer/issues/38), best workaround to prevent logging massive amount of errors into console, is to reconnect observer via [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const content = container.querySelector('.content');

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(event => { 
  const maxHeight = window.getComputedStyle(content).height.replace('px', '');
  const containerHeight = event[0].contentRect.height;
  
  resizeObserver.disconnect();
  
  if (containerHeight > maxHeight) {
    container.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => resizeObserver.observe(container));
});

resizeObserver.observe(container);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: max-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, molestiae? Officiis consequatur quod minima cum at ratione, sint ipsum architecto! Sit accusantium tenetur ducimus aut atque, eligendi in ullam sunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Maxime explicabo dolor sequi veritatis aut. Recusandae quibusdam maiores doloremque natus, aspernatur minus dignissimos, id soluta amet, blanditiis illum odio ab alias.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I click Run code snippet, I can resize the container a lot larger than the content... Also, "Try this" or "Try `code`" with no explanation of how it solves the user's problem are often downvoted.

Comment: I didn't understand what you were trying to achieve so I took it as a simple question with simple answer. Now I think that I understand what you are trying to achieve so I have updated my answer. Let me know if that helpes.

Comment: Thank you!  You have no idea how long I spent failing to compute the width/height of the content when it was being hidden by max-width/height.  This seems to work wonderfully.  I'm using something similar to automatically set the max-width/height of a container I want to be able to smoothly transition into or out of existence.

Answer (score 0):

I made a change to use JavaScript to set the max-height on the container with the offset set height from the content. That way it will not grow more than the content.

```
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="content" class="content">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, molestiae? Officiis consequatur quod minima cum at ratione, sint ipsum architecto! Sit accusantium tenetur ducimus aut atque, eligendi in ullam sunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Maxime explicabo dolor sequi veritatis aut. Recusandae quibusdam maiores doloremque natus, aspernatur minus dignissimos, id soluta amet, blanditiis illum odio ab alias.
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var content = document.getElementById("content");

  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  container.style.maxHeight = content.offsetHeight + "px";
</script>
```

Comment: The requirement is that you can resize the height of the container, if the content is overflowed, but you can't resize if the content is not overflowed. I know it works if max-height is set a fixed value like 80vh, 200px. But that is not what I want here.  Thanks.

Comment: Please check the new approach. Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/uc9r1bak/2/ works as expected.

Comment: @FredYang when you have a chance please review it! thanks!

Comment: @FredYang I hope you are having a nice day, please let me know if that soulition works for you :)